# How to select a cell in one column in the same row that the other cell, that is being edited in the other column using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been wondering if there was a way to select a cell in a particular column, when the other particular column has been edited, using Google Apps Script?
For example: **If someone edits B3, my script should select C3 (if someone edits B23, then C23), but someone edits let's say A5- then nothing happens.**
 
See the example picture below
Thank you in advance!

---

[image]

Comment: It could be two scripts. First one will write (via `onEdit()` trigger) on another sheet the index of the last edited row (if the edited cell belongs to column B). Second one will run manually (or via custom menu), it will take the stored row index and activate the a cell in column C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible through the `onEdit` trigger, data from the `e`/`event object`, and `.activate()`.

### Try:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === `Sheet1`) {

    if (e.range.rowStart === 5 && e.range.columnStart === 1) return

    e.source.getActiveSheet()
            .getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart+1)
            .activate()

  }

}
```

### Commented:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // If the sheet ('Sheet1') was edited.. 
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === `Sheet1`) {
    // "Cancel" if A5 was selected.
    if (e.range.rowStart === 5 && e.range.columnStart === 1) return

    // Get the active sheet
    e.source.getActiveSheet()
    // Select the range of "edited row", "edited column +1"
            .getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart+1)
            // "Select" the cell.
            .activate()

  }

}
```

If you would like to 'ignore' more than A5, please let me know and I can update the examples for you.

Learn More:

- [onEdit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Range.activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate)

Comment: Thank a lot. I'll try it out and comment on it a little later

Comment: No problem, I know you were just giving an example of what you wanted, but if you need something more specific, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == `YOUR SHEET NAME` && e.range.columnStart == 2 ) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).activate();
  }
}
```

[activate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate())